# How to design table and class when a column relative other table?

Tags: sql, database-design

For example:

```
table A
A.Id
A.Name
A.ImgId
A.InfoId

table B
B.Id
B.Name
B.ImgId
B.InfoId

table C
C.Id
C.Name
C.InfoId

table Img
Img.Id
Img.Content

table Info
Info.Id
Info.Name
Info.Content
```

Maybe B has Img, but C hasn't, so I don't want push Img in A table directly.
How to design the table and how to design the class.

I could be save the data.

Sometime will Show the data like:

```
A.Id
A.Name
A.ImgContent
A.InfoContent
```

Do I need add view for a,info,img b,info,img c,info create viewclass a,b,c and original class a,b,c?

Try not to duplicate the query layer code.

Comment: Your current design doesn't look bad actually.  Are you asking about the design or do you need help with a query?

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen:Yes,I have to show the A,B,C data. I could think about A,B,C derive from Info, and create view for A,Img,Info. then do I need create a class like the view class and original class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not direct use Table model for view model, add a viewmodel layer.